# Get Firebase document objects as Swift object

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to implement a simple shopping list swift application for iOS as a personal project. I did follow a guide for iOS on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwXEsKRYUXU).

My question is how do I parse the `Item` object from firebase to my `ShoppingListItem` swift object? If I execute the following code, it doesn't show any error message but it does not show any results either. If I uncomment all "items" lines, it shows the expected results without the item information.

Here is a screenshot from the firebase console of my [firebase firestore structure / example object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbjyN.png)

Thanks in advance!

---

### ShoppingListItem.swift

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any])
}

struct ShoppingListItem {
    var shoppingItemID: String
    var priority: Int
    var quantity: Int
    var item: Item

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "shoppingItemID": shoppingItemID,
            "priority": priority,
            "quantity": quantity,
            "item": item,
        ]
    }
}

extension ShoppingListItem: DocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let shoppingItemID = dictionary["shoppingItemID"] as? String,
            let priority = dictionary["priority"] as? Int,
            let quantity = dictionary["quantity"] as? Int,
            let item = dictionary["item"] as? Item
        else { return nil }


        self.init(shoppingItemID: shoppingItemID, priority: priority, quantity: quantity, item: item)
    }
}

struct Item {

    var itemID: String
    var lastPurchase: String
    var name: String
    var note: String
    var picturePath: String

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "itemID": itemID,
            "lastPurchase": lastPurchase,
            "name": name,
            "note": note,
            "picturePath": picturePath,
        ]
    }
}

extension Item: DocumentSerializable {

    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let itemID = dictionary["itemID"] as? String,
            let lastPurchase = dictionary["lastPurchase"] as? String,
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let note = dictionary["note"] as? String,
            let picturePath = dictionary["picturePath"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.init(itemID: itemID, lastPurchase: lastPurchase, name: name, note: note, picturePath: picturePath)
    }
}
```

---

### Get Data call in TableViewController.swift

```
        db.collection("shoppingList").getDocuments(){
            querySnapshot, error in

            if let error = error {
                print("error loading documents \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else{
                self.shoppingArray = querySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({ShoppingListItem(dictionary: $0.data())})

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the Codable protocol.

I used this as an extension to the Encodable Protocol:

```
extension Encodable {
  /// Returns a JSON dictionary, with choice of minimal information
  func getDictionary() -> [String: Any]? {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()

    guard let data = try? encoder.encode(self) else { return nil }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any]
    }
  }
}
```

Then I use this to decode:

```
extension Decodable {
  /// Initialize from JSON Dictionary. Return nil on failure
  init?(dictionary value: [String:Any]){

    guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) else { return nil }
    guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: []) else { return nil }

    guard let newValue = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: jsonData) else { return nil }
    self = newValue
  }
}
```

Make your two structs conform to Codable (Item first, then ShoppingListItem). Of course, this may not work for the existing data stored in Firestore. I would first put data into Firestore via the `getDictionary()` (in a new collection), then try to read it back into your tableView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did remove the protocol and extensions and added your code to my `ShoppingListItem.swift`. It now has the following suructure: `imports` - `your extensions` - `struct Item` - `struct ShoppingListItem`. 
Like you suggested I did put new data to a new collection and it did work! 
But how do I encode the data? The code in my question above does not work anymore and there is the following message: _"Missing argument for parameter 'priority' in call"_

Comment: I don't understand *how do I encode my data*? Are you asking how you should write the data to Firestore? I would assume you have some code that looks like `documentReference.setData(shoppingListItem.dictionary) { /** error closure */ }`. Replace the `dictionary` property with the `getDictionary()` method.

Comment: Sorry, I meant _decode_. How do I retrieve the data from Firestore because this does not work anymore:
 `self.shoppingArray = querySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({ShoppingListItem(dictionary: $0.data())})`

Comment: Any chance you are trying to import data that does NOT have a "priority" key? If so, that is the problem. The default import expects all properties to have key entries.

Comment: No this was a compiler error, not a runtime error. Somehow it compiles without an error now but it still does decode 0 objects even if there are five documents in the snapshot (`querySnapshot?.documents.count`). How would you store the documents in an array? Is the `ShoppingListItem(dictionary: $0.data())` still correct or does it need something like `ShoppingListItem(from: $0.data() as! Decoder)`?

Comment: Sorry, now it works! As you said, it does not work with the previous added entries and after I did delete everything, added new documents and it works with the `ShoppingListItem(dictionary: $0.data())`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to print the actual error when trying to Decode your data, this will greatly help you pinpoint the data error if there's any.

```
extension Decodable {
    /// Initialize from JSON Dictionary. Return nil on failure
    init?(dictionary value: [String:Any]) {
        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [])
            let newValue = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: jsonData)
            self = newValue
        }
        catch {
            log.error("failed to serialize data: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```